# Recommended pattern for REST service which requires HTTP headers?

Tags: servicestack

I am implementing a RESTful service which will be consumed by a Dojo framewwork's [RestStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html), which will permit binding the service to various widgets like an interactive grid or a type-ahead ajax select.

The `RestStore` wants to send and receive the HTTP `Range` and `Content-Range` headers in order to restrict the results of the queries to particular subrange.

What is the best practice pattern in ServiceStack (new API) for reacting to HTTP headers as part of the service?  Normally, the service method like `Get` doesn't have access to the HTTP headers, unless I have missed an alternate API.

The current way that I see is to implement an attribute like

```
 public class RangeSupporter : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter, IHasResponseFilter
```

which will parse the headers on request, and write the headers on response.  The DTO would then be marked for this filter.

The filter would transfer the values, say 'First' and 'Last' in and out of the DTO.  However, to know that the DTO even has such attributes, it would have to have some marker interface like

```
interface IHasRangeSupport {
    int First { set; get; }
    int Last { set; get; }
    int Total { set; get; }
}
```

so that the filter can transfer the information into and out of the DTO the with code similar to:

```
  var r = request as IHasRangeSupport;
  if (r != null) {
      /// Access the DTO attributes for the range parameters
  }
```

This seems like a lot of ceremony, and a very awkward implementation.

Is there a better pattern for accessing the HTTP headers when implementing a REST service?

In my particular use case, supporting non-REST endpoints (like SOAP) are not required.  Only the HTTP end-point is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the best practice pattern in ServiceStack (new API) for reacting to HTTP headers as part of the service?**

I believe you can get the headers in your service class...

```
public class FooService : Service
{
    public object Get(Foo reqeust)
    {
       //get header
       var h1 = base.RequestContext.GetHeader("headerName");
       //get header differently
       var h2 = base.Request.Headers.Get("headerName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, none of the example code I saw showed that--will be very, very helpful!

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer does solve your problem please mark it as the 'accepted answer' so others can find the solution as well.

Comment: I will once I have tested--note my rep across sites :-)  I know how to play the game :-)

Comment: Whoops - I'm new here and still learning how 'to play the game'. Didn't think to look at rep.